# Implication of inequality for limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have for two constants $c_1, c_2$ and two sequences $a_n$ and $\mu_n$ that $$ c_1 \mu_n \leq a_n \leq c_2 \mu_n $$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does this imply that there exists a constant $c_3$ such that $$ \frac{a_n}{\mu_n} \to c_3 \quad ?$$ Do I have to make any further assumptions about the sequences $a_n$ and $\mu_n$.

**Edit:** After some good points were raised in the answers below, I want to modify the question slightly:

Suppose $c_1,c_2 > 0$ and $a_n, \mu_n > 0$ for all $n$ and $a_n, \mu_n $ monotone in $n$. Is it true that there exists a constant $c_3 > 0$ such that $$ \frac{a_n}{\mu_n} \to c_3 \quad ?$$

Comment: What if $\mu_n$ is zero repeatedly?

Comment: It is considered bad form to modify a question after you have been given answers fully dealing with your original question. It is best to ask a new question and link to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_n=1$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$, $c_1=-1$, $c_2=1$, and $a_n=\sin (n)$. Clearly then $a_n/\mu_n=a_n$ is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mu_n$ is strictly positive for all $n$, then the given condition just says that
$$c_1\leq\frac{a_n}{\mu_n}\leq c_2.$$
All this tells you is that $a_n/\mu_n$ is a bounded sequence, which is obviously not enough to tell you that the sequence converges.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I were to assume that $a_n$ and $\mu_n$ converge to $0$, my statement would hold, right? Same, when I assume that $a_n$ and $\mu_n \to \infty$?

Comment: @MATH101 I don't see why that follows, for instance, we can pick $a_n=n(1+\sin n)$ and $\mu_n=n$, then $a_n,\mu_n$ both go to infinity, while $a_n/\mu_n$ is bounded by $0$ and $2$ but doesn't converge to anything.